# Access OWA via http://servername/exchange?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

In Exchange 2003 I could access my mailbox via `http://ex2003/exchange`.

First of all, I'm not sure if this is possible in Exchange 2010.  If it is, it's not working currently.

Our external OWA URL is `owa.domain.com`.  Internally, I should be able to use `http://ex2010/exchange`, but this a) throws a certificate error (which does not occur when using the external URL) and b) forwards to `https://webmail.domain.com/owa`, which isn't a valid URL regardless.

I believe I have misconfigured this somewhere, but I'm not sure where.  Under `owa Properties` in EMC, the internal URL is configured as `https://ex2010.domain.com/owa` and the external URL is `https://owa.domain.com/owa`.  I don't see `webmail` anywhere.

Can anyone advise what I've done wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: is domain.com your internal and external domain?  If not, what's the correct internal domain FQDN?  Need that to answer properly.

Comment: Yes, it is, much to my chagrin.  It's been like that for a dog's age, so not much I can do about it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a DNS entry in your local network that points "owa.domain.com" to your Exchange server's IP.

This should cause the cert to validate, and should keep it simpler for users.  They only need to remember a single web address for their email, no matter where they are.

Exchange Control Panel can be used to make changes to a user's account, as well as access your own mailbox for administrative purposes.

http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/47428

Comment: The reason I want to access `http://ex2010/exchange` is to access my mailbox without logging in (the behaviour in Exchange 2003), and to access other mailboxes, which I used to be able to do by going to `http://ex2003/exchange/username`.

Comment: Oh, gotcha.  Okay, this was actually made into a tool in the latest release:  Exchange Control Panel

http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/47428